# ¿Cómo multiplicar celdas de un Jtable (JAVA) al editar la tabla como en exel?

Tags: java, jtable, model

estoy realizan un sistema de facturacion y necesito que cuando modifique la columna cantidad se actualice el total de manera automatica (como en excel cuando en c1 se escribe =a1*b1)
En la imagen que anexo muestro la tabla y realice 3 ingresos,
el primero y segundo con cantidad 1 y 3 e importo el precio y la columna total la hago mediante código
en le tercer ingreso modifique la cantidad pero no se refleja cambio en la columna total

anexo código del botón agregar

```
DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel();

public frm_facturacion() {
        initComponents();
        cargar_jcombos();
        modelo.setColumnIdentifiers(new Object[]{"CODIGO", "DESCRIPCIÓN", "CANTIDAD", "PRECIO", "TOTAL"});
}

private void btn_agregar_cod_barrasActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                       

    if (jbox_cod_barras.getSelectedIndex() == 0) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Ingrese un numero de cedula");
    } else {

        int id = jbox_cod_barras.getItemAt(jbox_cod_barras.getSelectedIndex()).getId();
        ResultSet rs = DB_consultas_R_D.getTabla("select codigo_barras,descripcion,precio_venta from productos where id =" + id);

        try {
            while (rs.next()) {
                modelo.addRow(new Object[]{rs.getString("codigo_barras"), rs.getString("descripcion"), txt_cantidad.getText(), rs.getString("precio_venta"),
                    (Integer.parseInt(txt_cantidad.getText()) * rs.getDouble("precio_venta"))});
            }
            rs.close();
            jtabla_Ventas.setModel(modelo);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(frm_clientes.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Después de un tiempo encontré una solución excelente.

**este es el resultado**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Acepta decimales también

```
DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel() { // modelo de la tabla
    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int fila, int columna) { // solo se permiten editables la columan cantidad y precio
        if (columna == 3) { // Columna cantidad
            return columna == 3;
        }
        if (columna == 4) { // Columna precio
            return columna == 4;
        }
        return columna == 3;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) { // Sobre escritura del metodo getValue
        if (col == 5) { // digo que la columna 5 (Total) sera igual a la siguiente opreacion
            Double i; // i sera igual a la cantidad
            try {
                i = Double.parseDouble((String) getValueAt(row, 3)); // capturo la cantidad
            } catch (Exception e) {
                i = 1.0;
            }

            Double d = Double.parseDouble(metodos.EliminaCaracteres((String) getValueAt(row, 4), ".")); // d sera igual al precio
            if (i != null && d != null) {
                return formatea.format(i * d); // regreso el resultado de multiplicar la cantidad por el valor
            } else {
                return 0d;
            }
        }
        return super.getValueAt(row, col);

    }

    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int row, int col) {
        super.setValueAt(aValue, row, col);
        calcular_total(); // este metodo es para sumar el total 
        fireTableDataChanged(); // este metodo esta pendiente de cualquier cambio en la tabla
    }

};
```